# Data not accessible outside Promise.all()

Tags: javascript, promise

I have the below code to access movie sessions from a cinema site. I am looping using a while loop to fetch movie sessions.

And I intend to add the sessions within the loop to array `sessionResults` which is declared outside the while loop.

`R.` refers to the [Ramda library](https://ramdajs.com/docs/)

```
let page // passed as an argument to the outer function 

 let sessionResults = [];
  while (currentCinemaIndex < cinemaList.length) {
    await page.goto("www.fakeurl.com");

    const _movies = await movies({ page });

    //Get the sessions for each @_movies
    const _movieSessions = await _movies.map(
      async (_movie, index) => {
       //sessions() returns an array of objects
        const res = (await sessions({ page: page }, index + 1)).map(session => {
          return Object.assign({}, _movie, session);
        });
        return res;
      },
      { page }
    );

//!!! AREA OF CONCERN
    console.log(_movieSessions); // array of promises
    Promise.all(_movieSessions).then(p => {
      sessionResults = R.concat(R.flatten(p), sessionResults);
      // console.log(sessionResults); //  concatenated array 
    });
    console.log(sessionResults); //  [] 
    //while loop logic
    currentCinemaIndex  = //increment currentCinemaIndex  
    limit =// set new limit
```

If you look at `//!!! AREA OF CONCERN` I have documented the value of `sessionResults` at different places.

Could you please advise why the value of `sessionResults` is not carried through outside `Promise.all()`?

Comment: Does `sessionResults` when you assign it *inside the function* have the expected value? Also, does a call of `sessions` return a `Promise`?

Comment: *inside the `Promise.all`, that is

Comment: `sessions()` returns an array of objects . i have updated the code with that comment. 

yes `sessionResults` gets the value assigned inside `Promise.all()`

Although its a separate question, i dont mind having an implementation without Promise.all() if could change the code in some way.. The only reason I have `Promise.all()` is because `_movieSessions` is an array of Promises

Comment: If `sessions` returns an array and not a `Promise`, then you shouldn't `await` it. (similarly, `_movies.map` will also return an array, which isn't a `Promise`, so you shouldn't `await _movies.map` either)

Comment: You're basically trying to use `sessionResults` before it's been populated - either put all the logic that depends on it *inside* the `Promise.all` (or have the `Promise.all` call another function), or use `await Promise.all(...` instead

Comment: `await Promise.all()` worked.. thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`await Promise.all()` worked based on comment from @CertainPerformance

Revised code looks like

```
sessionResults = await Promise.all(_movieSessions).then(p => R.flatten(p));

console.log(sessionResults); //  concatenated array
```

Comment: Yes that will work but from what you say, you don't need to await `sessions()` or await `_movies.map(...)`. All that appears to be synchronous. 

If I'm right, then you will end up with `const _movieSessions = _movies.map(...)`, and `await Promise.all(_movieSessions).then(p => R.flatten(p))` will simplify to `sessionResults = R.flatten(_movieSessions)`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't get the updated value of `sessionResults` because by the time the code executes until the `console.log(sessionResults)` after `Promise.all(...)`, the promise has not resolved yet.

Therefore, the `sessionResults` returned by `console.log` is not yet updated.

What you can do instead is use `await` like below:

```
p = await Promise.all(_movieSesions);
sessionResults = R.concat(R.flatten(p), sessionResults);
console.log(sessionResults);
```

Please note that if you would use `await` like above, you need to do it inside an async function scope and not the global scope (because it is not async).

Comment: I don't think so. `_movies` is Array and `sessions()` returns Array, therefore everything after `const _movies = await movies({ page });` is plain simple synchronous treatment of `_movies`. No further async/await is required, nor `Promise.all()`.